# what’s the criteria SQL server (2014) will automatically recompile a stored procedure which has table variables?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone explain what’s the criteria SQL server (2014) will automatically recompile a stored procedure which has table variables? I know there is criteria for statistics but how about a proc using table variable not the temp table?

Comment: a procedure will run always with the give variables and will not be recompiled it will be parsed

Answer (score 1):

Tables variables doesn't trigger recompile.

Well, they do, but not until SQL Server 2019 where they are treated as temp tables in this aspect.